# How to list out the location of duplicated maximum value in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the table to show the NC quantity and C quantity of item 1.1a - 1.4e in excel file.

[image: Capture.jpg]

I want to find out the maximum value of C, that i use below formula in H4:

```
=MAX(C4:C22)
```

that show the maximum value of C is 8, then i want to find the maximum value corresponding to which item, so i use below formula in H5:

```
=(INDEX($A$4:$A$22,MATCH(H4,$C$4:$C$22,0)))
```

It shows only one result which is 1.1a, how can i list out all the item which has the maximum value which i use for vlookup the information?

Please find the Capture.jpg for your reference.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: My excel version is 365

Comment: Use `FILTER` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FILTER()` with `MAX()` formula.

```
 =FILTER(A2:A6,C2:C6=MAX(C2:C6))
```

[image]

> Edit: To display result in single cell with comma separated use below formula.

```
 =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A2:A6,C2:C6=MAX(C2:C6)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, can the filtered result shown in one cell or column?

Comment: @AlanTse Yes, you can. How you want to show them, comma separated?

Comment: @Harun24HR Yes, i want to show them by comma separated.

Comment: @AlanTse If your problem is solved then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it). Then our visitor will know that this thread is solved.